# Python Regex for Numeric Pattern that has Dashes

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a column in a pandas data frame called sample_id.  Each entry contains a string, from this string I'd like to pull a numeric pattern that will have one of two forms

1-234-5-6789

or

123-4-5648

I'm having trouble defining the correct regex pattern for this.  So far I have been experimenting with the following:

```
re.findall(pattern=r'\b2\w+', string=str(data['sample_id']))
```

But this is only pulling values that are starting with 2 and only the first chunk of the numeric pattern.  How do I express the above patterns with the dashes?

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want only the numbers?

Comment: Numbers and hyphens would be best.

Comment: Something like [(?<!\[\d-\])(?:\d-)?\d{3}-\d-\d{4}(?!\[\d-\])](https://regex101.com/r/BQOXqc/1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vertical pipe `|` makes an OR in a regular expression, so you can use:

```
test1='123-4-5648'
test2='1-234-5-6789'

re.findall(pattern=r'[0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{3}-[0-9]-[0-9]{4}', string=test1)
re.findall(pattern=r'[0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{3}-[0-9]-[0-9]{4}', string=test2)
```

`[0-9]` matches a single digit in the range `0` through `9` (inclusive), `{4}` indicates that four such digits should occur in a row, `-` means a hyphen, and `|` means an OR and separates the two patterns you mention.

Answer (score 1):

You could match an optional part `(?:\d-)?` to match 1 digit and a hypen, followed by `\d{3}-\d-\d{4}` which will match the pattern of the digits for both the examples.

`(?:\d-)?\d{3}-\d-\d{4}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dDhBnU/1)

Instead of using a word boundary `\b`, if there can not be a non whitespace character  before your value, you could prepend the regex with `(?<!\S)` and if there can not be a non whitespace character after you could add `(?!\S)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If there will only a maximum of one hyphen between two numbers then, `^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+$` would work well. It uses the `normal*(special normal*)*` pattern where `normal` is `[0-9]` and `special` is `-`.

Comment: This matches `1-1111111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1`, which is not one of OP's patterns.